# how to render searched item first and all match item JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

#### I Need to render John Daniel at the top and then other matched word as well

```js
let searchPerson = "John Daniel"
Person = [ 
"Harry Daniel", 
"John Daniel", 
"Michael Jackson", 
"Anup Jackson",
]
let mySearch = searchPerson.toLowerCase().split(' ')
console.log(Person.filter(string => {
let containsAtLeastOneWord = false;

mySearch.forEach(word => {
    if (string.toLowerCase().includes(word))
        containsAtLeastOneWord = true;
})
if (containsAtLeastOneWord)
    return string
}))
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: You'll have to edit your matching rules to enforce an ordering of names. i.e. Check for a complete match or x words matching etc.and sort them in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simple approach is by considering the number of keywords matched, and then pushing the relevant ones to the top and rest to the end.  You may try below and add additional validations if required.

```js
let searchPerson = "John Daniel"
Person = [ 
"Harry Daniel", 
"John Daniel", 
"Michael Jackson", 
"Anup Jackson",
]
let mySearch = searchPerson.toLowerCase().split(' ');
let list = new Array();
let temp = 0;

Person.forEach(name => {
  temp = 0;
  mySearch.forEach(word => {
    if (name.toLowerCase().indexOf(word) >= 0)
     temp++;
 })
  if ( temp > 1 )
   list.unshift(name); //Push to the top
  else if ( temp == 1 )
    list.push(name);
});
console.log("List: " + list);
```

Comment: Hey, Bro
Thank You Very much for the answer..
It Works..I'm really happy..

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, in case you don't have any alternative.

```js
function getDifference(a, b){
 var i = 0;
 var j = 0;
 var result = "";
 
 while (j < b.length){
  if (a[i] != b[j] || i == a.length)
   result += b[j];
  else
   i++;
  j++;
 }
 return result;
}

let searchPerson = "John Daniel";

Person = [
 "Harry Daniel",
 "John Jackson",
 "John Daniel",
 "Michael Jackson",
 "Anup Jackson",
 "Anup John",
];

let mySearch = searchPerson.toLowerCase().split(' ');

let filteredPerson = Person.filter(string => {
 let containsAtLeastOneWord = false;

 mySearch.forEach(word => {
 if (string.toLowerCase().includes(word))
  containsAtLeastOneWord = true;
 })

 if (containsAtLeastOneWord)
 return string
});

let sortedfilteredPerson = filteredPerson.sort(function (a, b) {
 return getDifference(searchPerson, a).length - getDifference(searchPerson, b).length;
});

console.log(sortedfilteredPerson);
```

Comment: Thank you..Bro, I am working on search and it helps me a lot..